# How to copy data that match certain criteria from an Excel workbook to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

After some processing I have two different Excel workbooks. One workbook (A) has certain clients (about 500 people) who we need to contact. The data in workbook (A) contains these peoples names and ID numbers although NOT their contact info.

The other workbook (B) is a larger file with info about all our clients (almost 1500 people), and this data includes the contact info plus names and ID numbers.

The question here is how can I get the contact info (telephone numbers) for those 500 people from workbook B and copy it to workbook A?

Being a novice Excel user I'd very much like to know how to efficiently accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into the VLOOKUP function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I mean I understand I should use some kind of function and that VLOOKUP is a really powerful one. I'm not sure on how I should syntax the formula to get the right results though.

Comment: any sample data/file you can share.. so that we can replicate the case? Or else I'd suggest you to try out [index-match](https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact). and share where you stuck/tried at..